# Typed Guid cannot be used as an index

Tags: typescript, types

We a TypeScript app and are thinking about adding a `Guid` type, like this:

```
declare type Guid = string & { isGuid: true }
```

This has  benefit that you cannot accidentally assign just any string to `Guid`, at least without casting it first. But it has the following problem:

```
const a: Record<Guid, number> = { '3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6': 42 };
const b: Guid = '3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6';
const c: number = a[b];
// Error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
// 'string & { isGuid: true; }' can't be used to index type 'Record<string & { isGuid: true; }, number>'.
```

Is there a TypeScript setting to allow this? If I don't declare `c`'s type and hover over it, it correctly dispalys `number`. Maybe the editor (VS Code) is using a different compiler that the TypeScript executable? Is there a way to fix it?

- Operation system: Windows 10
- TypeScript version: 3.7.0
- NodeJS version: 17.0.1
- VSCode version: 1.61.2

Answer (score 1):

The below code uses TypeScript 4.1.

It's getting late here but feel free to ask me questions and I'll edit the answer later. Just as a suggestion you may want to do the below instead using type guards.

The main type is here:

```
type GUID<
    s1 extends string = string,
    s2 extends string = string,
    s3 extends string = string,
    s4 extends string = string,
    s5 extends string = string
> = `${s1}-${s2}-${s3}-${s4}-${s5}`
```

It covers most cases but the cases it doesn't cover need a type guard which I split into three seperate functions:

```
function guidOctetPart<GP extends string, L extends number>(guidPart: GP, length: L): guidPart is string {
    return guidPart.length === length;
}

function isGuid(guid: string): guid is GUID {
    const [o1,o2,o3,o4,o5] = guid.split("-");
    return ([[o1, 8], [o2, 4], [o3, 4], [o4, 4], [o5, 12]] as const).every(([guidPart, length]) => guidOctetPart(guidPart, length))
}

function isGuidRecord (guid: Record<GUID, number>): guid is Record<GUID, number> {
    return Object.keys(guid).every(isGuid) && Object.values(guid).every(x => typeof x === "number");
}
```

More details in the playground link and code below... Mainly through the use of comments.

[Playground Link (or look at code right below)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEoFQCwSwZ1AYwPYFcA2ATUB3ZAnAa1BgDNQAXWBeOVAU1AHN6KFSYAPe7KCigA5wAXCCYwqqAEYA6FAFtg8mInzI4yUhWAQAngPoBlVTAHbaDOMADMAFgBsATgBMAKBCV9jAOIBVAJIAIgA87mDg4OgAjKD0nBT0AHaYCImo8lL0+KAAvKBpGVkANGERkc6x8Ukp+emZ2XkF9SUeZejWlQnJqXVZubWF+C3hEei2ndU9g-1NxaVtAKwT3QP1M71DoPMRcDFxXTVwFPgwiUz9Rydnw2WgcBX7k3fHp+d5l683ZXAdjysfZwuL2u23AcHGf0OwLezyuTC+OyWkIQAJhqNKAD5+gADAAkAG9dqAAGSgfHoJJMKjCUDRAC+dIAtAT7iSyRSztTac4GczCR1SeTKVz2ryWeNBRyqVAaWMxYSlpLhTLaQsGdjSgAxAj5ZA4XCMFAYbCYZCUagyS26iigACGCCYyGQ2CkqBtiHQ6kYSTQTCgMlcFC8oD8QVC3z2VX+0KBcJK3weUahcNjn1c31+SZRMfe0PjOwhWdhr1TIO+SKLqNLTFcWLyeMJUSZLJ5fJ+zcJtg7cDVGtK3lQMF49soTtApHo+oEtvwbFcKESR1AmttMHQuxpocC-QARAsovvD4yolF7KfT8eAOxRa+Xq83h87rb9wfDhAUMfyW2JXSgaezhB52QRcbRXNd7k3AJtzyPcDzghZj3PM97HvW9UIfY9nDsKJbBwxlcIInCcKfVxSgENQDGyLcSAQW10E9HAeCAkDQAABXtOB6A3EMoN3KIsNsBZ7EvAAOTC7HE2xJMkoTRMcAAGfidwAblIjxEFtAA3ehbQoGkAEF6L1BAcDUQEpSoHhGX-NgeKCOBmKXdi4E4iC7Og0Ad34iTD3gxDkIvB80KCx9nw8CAAHlQH0gA1CKgnNRhbSkZBtKQLSdJtXQ0DuKA0CwUBUE48dUESRAKBgYDPAMZhUBnFI1LAQw8v1b9QGQKRNMqor0F-MD0BLfB6BQfBMFcMgAAp4AHIcACVhoITAJvxABtLyBJ3ABdGkmwASl2sl0wiBcNApGRPSYCadwAdWAgByG16G07ILpkHcDo8IMavgO10BwW1dAdZASw-UBMjtdySHICRYkSBJ8AQKAsnoVw6UatiKL6aicDXdBaWQGtJum195pGpbVuc1yom20AeX2w6yhO5Azouq7rtx37-sB-GmDe3bUfRmB5HI5BKNqodcA5xJkBtC7Ym0xJzV9KASBtacXK46rDSRxBCAcom4BmzBScW5aVsprjnBpumDvxI7wCZlmCbZ+7Huenm+YF1xSFK8rKsVphXwi8rWHY2dgm8VjlmTT5QAAGWjqZ6gxCbA6HMO9JDViilpZUaTj3aaTTzAM5o4tATtsohooVB8AD18M-O5VchyPILKgVS0e932Kqq4mh1T18aVRQvxewH7qMr47gKXFbkCiIpkGcRfrEX2xF4WTb+mLmQ4AEAaKCuxl3tUqvWFrxWJpWueF9AETNpzufl9AWwH9AOfV5ft+5-Xr-H+QBYOd+KbS3iOE6FBdoyCelkXQE0r7Fwzjndum0Do5CxMXYOCQKAZ0HunGcFAkHKn2l7H2ZVe6K37sbBao1QC4MwDSE2o0I5QRzrMfAGJR7FzLowzAzCgisI2FiKe4Bq4X1ABFKQAArYaFAZCEHoIDOhkDoH4FgZQg6xJSQSOkeVGQmk6KWCUVA56sDOC5CxF9egmhQBmNbjBNhJ8vZAA)

```
//  This could work if this issue gets fixed https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34692
// type GUID<
//     l1 extends number = number,
//     l2 extends number = number,
//     l3 extends number = number,
//     l4 extends number = number,
//     l5 extends number = number, 
//     s1 extends string = string,
//     s2 extends string = string,
//     s3 extends string = string,
//     s4 extends string = string,
//     s5 extends string = string
// > = `${s1 & {length: l1}}-${s2 & {length: l2}}-${s3 & {length: l3}}-${s4 & {length: l4}}-${s5 & {length: l5}}`
// For now we could do this... not as good but close enough.
type GUID<
    s1 extends string = string,
    s2 extends string = string,
    s3 extends string = string,
    s4 extends string = string,
    s5 extends string = string
> = `${s1}-${s2}-${s3}-${s4}-${s5}`

// Guid has too few parts
const Fails1: GUID = "5151515-1161616-171717-1717171" 

// Guid has too many parts 
const Fails2: GUID = "5151515-1161616-171717-1717171-12341414-414141414" 

// proper GUID is allowed
const Passes1: GUID = "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012";

// caveat: Allows wrong lengthed-parts GUIDs
const Passes2: GUID = "1234-5151515-1161616-171717-1717171" 

// TO AVOID the above caveat you should use function type guards

// Show an obviously Failing record
if(isGuidRecord({["1234"]: 1})) {
    console.log("Won't ever log.") // type is always going to be a GUID if it enters here
}

// Proper GUID will log
if(isGuidRecord({[Passes1]: 2})) {
    console.log("Will always log.")
}

// improper guid will not log even though it passes type checks
if(isGuidRecord({[Passes2]: 2})) {
    console.log("Won't ever log.")
}

function guidOctetPart<GP extends string, L extends number>(guidPart: GP, length: L): guidPart is string {
    return guidPart.length === length;
}

function isGuid(guid: string): guid is GUID {
    const [o1,o2,o3,o4,o5] = guid.split("-");
    return ([[o1, 8], [o2, 4], [o3, 4], [o4, 4], [o5, 12]] as const).every(([guidPart, length]) => guidOctetPart(guidPart, length))
}

function isGuidRecord (guid: Record<GUID, number>): guid is Record<GUID, number> {
    return Object.keys(guid).every(isGuid) && Object.values(guid).every(x => typeof x === "number");
}
```

See the JS Output of the above playground:

```js
"use strict";
// Guid has too few parts
const Fails1 = "5151515-1161616-171717-1717171";
// Guid has too many parts 
const Fails2 = "5151515-1161616-171717-1717171-12341414-414141414";
// proper GUID is allowed
const Passes1 = "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012";
// caveat: Allows wrong lengthed-parts GUIDs
const Passes2 = "1234-5151515-1161616-171717-1717171";
// Show an obviously Failing record
if (isGuidRecord({ ["1234"]: 1 })) {
    console.log("Won't ever log."); // type is always going to be a GUID if it enters here
}
// Proper GUID will log
if (isGuidRecord({ [Passes1]: 2 })) {
    console.log("Will always log.");
}
// improper guid will not log
if (isGuidRecord({ [Passes2]: 2 })) {
    console.log("Won't ever log.");
}
function guidOctetPart(guidPart, length) {
    return guidPart.length === length;
}
function isGuid(guid) {
    const [o1, o2, o3, o4, o5] = guid.split("-");
    return [[o1, 8], [o2, 4], [o3, 4], [o4, 4], [o5, 12]].every(([guidPart, length]) => guidOctetPart(guidPart, length));
}
function isGuidRecord(guid) {
    return Object.keys(guid).every(isGuid) && Object.values(guid).every(x => typeof x === "number");
}
```

Comment: This isn't *quite* what I was looking for, but simply upgrading to TypeScript 4.4 solved the issue for me.